# Filter services by path in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have a spring-boot application with some REST services grouped under `/api` path.

I have some other services grouped under `/management` path which I don't want them to be displayed in `/v2/api-docs`.

I use springfox dependencies to generate swagger documentation:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I filter out services starting with `/management` url in swagger json?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add tags to the definitions. There is no automated way that I know of

```
paths:
  "/management":
    get:
     tags:
       - Management
     summary: Manages something
     ...
  "/v2/api-docs:
     get:
     tags:
       - Documentation
     summary: Docs
     ...
```